# Conditional sentences and usages

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, grammaticality, conditional-constructions

1. If I were born in 1984 my name would have been thamilay.
2. If I were born in 1984 my name would be thamilay now.

Which sentence is wrong.
Correct me!

Comment: Don't ask "which is wrong".  Please explain why this is confusing for you.  Remember to use  a capital letter for your name. Check the formatting before you post the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are equally correct, and equally odd English.

Both start with a hypothetical condition.  This is odd, since you probably know which year you were born in,  so why hypothesise? If you know you were not born in 1984, you should use a counterfactual condition "If I had been born in 1984".  If you know you were born in 1984 you should not use a conditional, say "My name is Thamilay because I was born in 1984."

The second part refers to your name in the past, and your name now.  But names don't normally change much so we can assume that your past name is your current name (unless in your culture names *do* change, in which case you'd need to explain that). It might be more natural to refer to your parents naming you, rather than to your name. It might be more natural to use "name" as a verb.

Finally it is odd, since in Western culture, your name doesn't depend on the year you are born.  So either your name culture is very different from that in England, or your sentence is odd.  A more realistic sentence might be:

> If I hadn't been born on the 31st of December, I would have been named "Eleanor". But my parents changed their minds and named me "Eve". (*31st Dec is New Years Eve*)

This presents a counterfactual, and uses a "third conditional"

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I notice that you haven't accepted any of the answers given to you. If you feel that this answer has solved your problem you can show it by clicking the green "tick" next to the answer.  You should do that on the answer that solves your problem best.

Comment: I still don't know how to reply for answers.Here I want to say that I accept your answer @James.

Comment: Please take our [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Yes@James K.I will obey.